# Theorem 6.7 in Achim Klenke's Probability Theory

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces

I'm confused about both directions in the following proof about convergence:

[image: theorem 6.7]

In the forward direction, how do we get the first inequality, namely $$\tilde{d}_N(f,f_n)\leq \mu(A_N\cap\{d(f,f_n)>\varepsilon\})+\varepsilon\mu(A_N)$$
My work so far:

$$\tilde{d}_N(f,f_n)=\int_{A_N\cap \{ d(f,f_n)>1 \}} d(f,f_n)d\mu+\int_{A_N\cap \{ d(f,f_n)\leq 1 \}} 1d\mu$$ $$=\int_{A_N\cap \{d (f,f_n)>1 \}} d(f,f_n)d\mu+\mu(A_N\cap \{ d(f,f_n)\leq 1 \}) $$

Then $$\int_{A_N \cap \{d(f,f_n)>1\}} d(f,f_n) d\mu \leq \int_{A_N \cap \{d(f,f_n)>\varepsilon\}} d(f,f_n) d\mu$$ and $$\mu( A_N \cap \{d(f,f_n)\leq 1\}) \leq \mu(A_N)$$ but I don't think this is the right path, as that final integral of $d(f,f_n)$ would be greater than $\mu(A_N \cap \{d(f,f_n)>\varepsilon\})$ since $d(f,f_n)>1$ on the domain of the integral, right? And additionally $\mu(A_N)>\varepsilon\mu(A_N)$.

For the reverse direction, my question is already asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3403636/conditional-markov-inequality-using-conditional-measures), but I wanted to ask, is the accepted solution really the intended proof? That seems like a very involved process to just skip over and write as 1 step, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$Usually, $x\wedge y$ denotes the "meet" or the infimum of two quantities. I think you're running into difficulties because you're interpreting it as the supremum.

$$\begin{align}\int_{A_N}(1\wedge d(f,f_n))&=\int_{A_N\cap\{d(f,f_n)>\epsilon\}}(1\wedge d(f,f_n))+\int_{A_N\cap\{d(f,f_n)\le\epsilon\}}(1\wedge d(f,f_n))\\&\le\int_{A_N\cap\{d(f,f_n)<\epsilon\}}1+\int_{A_N\cap\{d(f,f_n)\le\epsilon\}}\epsilon\\&\le\mu(A_N\cap\{d(f,f_n)>\epsilon\})+\epsilon\mu(A_N)\end{align}$$In particular because $1\wedge d(f,f_n)\le1$ by definition of infimum.

Comment: Ah... yes, that'll do it. I definitely mixed up $\wedge$ and $\vee$, thank you!

Comment: @modz it's very easy to do. I don't like these notations for that reason. I guess $\wedge$ has the tip going "up" suggesting it's moving to $x,y$ from below so it is the infimum. You're welcome anyway